# Nestjs/Typeorm is adding "_rid" to my relation name

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, nestjs, typeorm

i'm developing a project with users that has student and instructor role with their relations. It was going all well but now i'm not able to post something with his relation, seems like Typeorm is adding "_rid" to the name of my relations. 
I searched for it but I found nothing. It's working fine in single post (ex. add user) but not working when I try to create student with level, sports, dates...

```
Controller.ts      
@Post()
      create(
        @Body() createStudentDto: CreateStudentDto,
        @GetUser() user: User,
      ): Promise<void> {
        return this._studentService.createStudent(createStudentDto, user);
      }

Service.ts
createStudent(createStudentDto: CreateStudentDto, user: User): Promise<void> {
    return this._studentRepository.createStudent(createStudentDto, user);
  }

Repository.ts
async createStudent(
    createStudentDto: CreateStudentDto,
    user: User,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const foundUser = await User.findOne(user.id);
    foundUser.details = createStudentDto.details;
    foundUser.sports = createStudentDto.sports;
    foundUser.level = createStudentDto.level;
    foundUser.calendar = createStudentDto.calendar;
    foundUser.save();
  }

CreateStudent.dto.ts
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { Sport } from 'src/modules/sport/sport.entity';
import { Level } from 'src/modules/level/level.entity';
import { UserCalendar } from 'src/modules/calendar/user-calendar.entity';
import { UserDetails } from '../../user.details.entity';

export class CreateStudentDto {
  @Type(type => UserDetails)
  details: UserDetails;

  @Type(type => Sport)
  sports: Sport[];

  @Type(type => Level)
  level: Level;

  @Type(type => UserCalendar)
  calendar: UserCalendar[];
}

import {
  BaseEntity,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  OneToOne,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  OneToMany,
  ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserDetails } from './user.details.entity';
import { Role } from '../role/role.entity';
import { status } from '../../shared/entity-status.enum';
import { UserCalendar } from '../calendar/user-calendar.entity';
import { Language } from '../language/language.entity';
import { Target } from '../target/target.entity';
import { StudentTarget } from './student/student-target.entity';
import { Course } from '../course/course.entity';
import { Sport } from '../sport/sport.entity';
import { Level } from '../level/level.entity';

@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  password: string;

  @OneToOne(type => UserDetails, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'detail_id' })
  details: UserDetails;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => Role,
    role => role.users,
    { eager: true },
  )
  @JoinTable({ name: 'user_roles' })
  roles: Role[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Language, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'user_languages' })
  languages: Language[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Target, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'student_targets',
    joinColumn: { name: 'student_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'target_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  targets!: Target[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Course, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'course_students',
    joinColumn: { name: 'student_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'course_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  studentCourses!: Course[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Course, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'course_instructors',
    joinColumn: { name: 'instructor_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'course_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  instrucorCourses!: Course[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Sport, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_sports',
    joinColumn: { name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'sport_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  sports!: Sport[];

  @OneToMany(
    type => StudentTarget,
    studentTarget => studentTarget.validatedBy,
  )
  studentTargetValidations: StudentTarget[];

  @OneToMany(
    type => UserCalendar,
    calendar => calendar.user,
    { eager: true },
  )
  calendar: UserCalendar[];

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Level,
    level => level.users,
    { cascade: true },
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'level_id' })
  level: Level;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: status.ACTIVE, length: 8 })
  status: status;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}

> query failed: SELECT User_targets_rid.target_id AS "target_id", User_targets_rid.student_id AS "student_id" FROM "targets" "targets" INNER JOIN "student_targets" "User_targets_rid" ON (User_targets_rid.student_id = $1 AND User_targets_rid.target_id = "targets"."id") ORDER BY User_targets_rid.target_id ASC, User_targets_rid.student_id ASC -- PARAMETERS: [2]
error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_targets_rid"
```

[Query error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qu8L.png)

Any suggestion? need you know something more to be able to help me? I have no idea that what could be happing.

Thanks

Comment: Where/how is your `User` entity defined?

Comment: hi, William, added the entity

Answer (score 0):

An example that when the error happens and when doesn't happen:
NOT HAPPENS

```
async createStudent(
    createStudentDto: CreateStudentDto,
    user: User,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const foundUser: User = await User.findOne(user.id);
    const level = await Level.findOne(createStudentDto.level.id);
    const targets = await Target.createQueryBuilder('t')
      .innerJoin('t.level', 'l')
      .where('l.order <= :order', { order: level.order })
      .getMany();
    console.log(targets);

    await this.createQueryBuilder()
      .update(UserDetails)
      .set(createStudentDto.details)
      .where('id = :id', { id: foundUser.id })
      .execute();

    await UserCalendar.createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into('user_calendar')
      .values(createStudentDto.calendar)
      .execute();

    foundUser.sports = createStudentDto.sports;
    foundUser.level = createStudentDto.level;
    foundUser.languages = createStudentDto.languages;
    //foundUser.targets = targets;

    foundUser.save();
  }
```

HAPPENS just not commenting this:

```
foundUser.targets = targets;
```

When I don't comment that line, appears this error:

```
query failed: SELECT User_targets_rid.target_id AS "target_id", User_targets_rid.student_id AS "student_id" FROM "targets" "targets" INNER JOIN "student_targets" "User_targets_rid" ON (User_targets_rid.student_id = $1 AND User_targets_rid.target_id = "targets"."id") ORDER BY User_targets_rid.target_id ASC, User_targets_rid.student_id ASC -- PARAMETERS: [101]
error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_targets_rid"
```

Target and student_targets entities:

```
Target.ts
import {
  BaseEntity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToMany,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Level } from '../level/level.entity';
import { User } from '../user/user.entity';
import { Sport } from '../sport/sport.entity';

@Entity('targets')
export class Target extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100, nullable: false, unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column({ name: 'level_id' })
  levelId: number;

  @Column({ name: 'sport_id' })
  sportId: number;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => User,
    user => user.targets,
  )
  students!: User[];

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Level,
    level => level.target,
    { eager: true },
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'level_id' })
  level: Level;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Sport,
    sport => sport.target,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'sport_id' })
  sport: Level;
}
Student_Targets.ts
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  BaseEntity,
  JoinColumn,
  PrimaryColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../user.entity';

@Entity('student_targets')
export class StudentTarget extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'student_id',
    primary: true,
    unique: false,
  })
  studentId!: number;

  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'target_id',
    primary: true,
    unique: false,
  })
  targetId!: number;

  @Column({ name: 'validated_by', nullable: true })
  validatedBy: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'date' })
  date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  feedback: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'validated_by' })
  instructor!: User;
}
```